# Como usar doctrine en un servicio propio definido en symfony

Tags: symfony3, symfony, doctrine, servicio

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web usando el concepto de ***servicios de symfony 3.4***
Dicho servicio efectua consultas con dql de doctrine, estas funcionan correctamente si las uso de otro controllador. Sin embargo, cuando las quiero usar en el servicio definido me genera el siguiente error:

```
Call to a member function has() on null
```

El servicio esta definido en archivo service.yml como

```
gestionar_turnos:
    class: ComensalesBundle\Controller\GestionTurnoController
```

El metodo que estoy ejecutando es el siguiente

```
/**
* @Route("/turnos",name="turnos")     * 
*/
public function mostrarPanel()
{
    //return $this->render('Panel turnos/panelTurnos.html.twig');

     $servicio = $this->get('gestionar_turnos');
     $sedes = $servicio->obtenerSedes();
    return $this->render('Panel turnos/panelTurnos.html.twig',
            array('sedes' => $sedes,
                 )
            );        
}
```

Supongo que debe ser un problema de definicion del servicio, posiblemente necesite algun argumento adicional. Por otro lado, ¿es correcto llamar al servicio como

```
$servicio = $this->get('gestionar_turnos');
```

Ante todo, les agradesco la buena predispoción y toda ayuda es bienvenida. Estoy aprendiendo symfony y la comunidad stackoverflow me ha ayudado mucho.
Saludos y buen sabado!

Comment: Hay algo que no me queda claro, según la documentación de sf 3.4: los controladores no necesitan ser declarados como servicios

Comment: Francisco Me podrìas proporcionar un ejemplo de como se deberia declarar el servicio en sf 3.4, gracias

Comment: Tomando como punto de partida tu código, solamente le falta en el fichero services.yml agregarle como argumento el entity manager.

Comment: Hola Francisco, podrias responder la respuesta para poder marcarla como resuelta y que a otros usuarios les sea util. Muchas gracias por tu buena predisposicion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les paso como puede resolverlo por si para otros miembros de la comunidad le es util.
Modifique la definicion de mi servicio a la siguiente forma:

```
    gestionar_turnos:
    class: ComensalesBundle\Controller\GestorTurnoController
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    public: true
```

Lo importante es la inclusión del parametro arguments que es requerido para accceder a Doctrine en el servicio que definimos.
Por otra parte, lei que es necesario que sea publico desde la versión 3.x de symfony.

Ademas, debi incluir un atributo privado y un constructor en mi servicio

```
   class GestorTurnoController extends Controller{
protected $entityManager;

public function __construct($entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function obtenerSedes()
{
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('s.id,s.nombreSede')
       ->from('ComensalesBundle:Sede','s')
       ->orderBy('s.nombreSede','ASC')
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

Finalmente, lo llamo desde la funcion en la que lo necesito de la siguiente forma:

```
$this->container->get('gestionar_turnos')->obtenerSedes();
```